# What am I doing wrong in c file, so it's giving `SystemError`?

Tags: python, python-c-extension

I'm learning how to make C extensions that can be used in Python.

I followed a tutorial (basically, copy pasted it, **but not blindly** , to try out). The code is

```
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject *exmodError;

static PyObject* exmod_say_hello(PyObject* self, PyObject *args){
    const char* msg;
    int sts = 0;

    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &msg)){
        return NULL;
    }

    if(strcmp("this_is_error_msg", msg) == 0){
        PyErr_SetString(exmodError, "Well, an error occured.");
        return NULL;
    }else{
        printf("In C world\nYour message is : %s\n", msg);
        sts = 21;
    }

    return Py_BuildValue("i", sts);
}

static PyObject* exmod_add(PyObject* self, PyObject *args){
    double a, b;
    double sts = 0;
    return NULL;

    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "dd", &a, &b)){
        return NULL;
    }

    sts = a + b;
    printf("This is C world, addition of %f + %f is %f", a, b, sts);

    return Py_BuildValue("d", sts);
}

static PyMethodDef exmod_methods[] = {
    // "PythonName", "C-FunctionName", "ArgumentPresentation", 
    // "Description"
    {"say_hello", exmod_say_hello, METH_VARARGS, "Say Hello from C and print message."},
    {"add", exmod_add, METH_VARARGS, "Add two numbers in C."},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC initexmod(void){
    PyObject *m;
    m = Py_InitModule("exmod", exmod_methods);

    if(m == NULL){
        return;
    }

    exmodError = PyErr_NewException("exMod.err", NULL, NULL);
    Py_INCREF(exmodError);

    pyModule_AddObject(m, "error", exmodError);
}
```

Above, file has dummy functions, that do mindless things.

Then, the setup.py, file is

```
__author__ = 'some.author'

from distutils.core import setup, Extension

module1 = Extension('exmod',
    include_dirs=["/usr/local/include", "/usr/include/python2.7"],
    sources=["exmodmodule.c"]
)

setup(
    name="exmod",
    version="1.0.0",
    description="This is a tutorial Package",
    author="someOne",
    url="www.9gag.com",
    ext_module=[module1]
)
```

I've built and installed it successfully. But when I import it in python interpreter and run exmod.add, an error occurs.

```
>>> exmod.add(5.0, 6.7)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
SystemError: error return without exception set
```

Please, help me figure out '**What I am doing wrong**' as I'm newbie in making C-extensions.

Comment: Clearly `distutils.core.Extension.__init__` requires more arguments; you're only giving it `include_dirs` and `sources`. Have you read the documentation for that module?

Comment: hi, just found the solution, `Extension` constructor should be given an extra string attr.

Comment: Should I delete the question?

Comment: @pnv You can self-answer if you want.

Comment: Well, I've edited it again, as I'm unable to find the cause of `SystemError`.

Comment: Provide a full text of your c file

Comment: It's the one that begins with `#include<Python.h>`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at line 3 of the function `exmod_add`. There you return `NULL` which signals that an exception was raised. But since you didn't raise an exception, you get the `SystemError: error return without exception set` instead.

```
static PyObject* exmod_add(PyObject* self, PyObject *args){
    double a, b;
    double sts = 0;
    return NULL;           /***** this one *****/

    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "dd", &a, &b)){
        return NULL;
    }

    sts = a + b;
    printf("This is C world, addition of %f + %f is %f", a, b, sts);

    return Py_BuildValue("d", sts);
}
```